# jq: modify string values based on values of keys in parents

Tags: json, string, replace, conditional-statements, jq

I have a JSON structure like this:

```
{
    "misc": {
        "color": "blue",
        "id": "yyyy-12345",
        "birthdate": "2020-12-25",
        "tools": [
            {
                "type": "power",
                "name": "hammer"
            },
            {
                "type": "manual",
                "name": "grinder"
            }
        ]
    },
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "bob",
            "profession": "analyst",
            "clients": [
                {
                    "name": "alice",
                    "instance": "3",
                    "stringA": "prefix1/suffix-stuff"
                },
                {
                    "name": "richard",
                    "instance": "2",
                    "stringA": "prefix1/suffix-stuff-lkasjdlflsd",
                    "stringB": "prefix2/suffix-stuff-lllaksjllsdkf",
                    "stringC": "prefix2/suffix-stuff-jhfhklasldj"
                },
                {
                    "name": "melanie",
                    "instance": "0",
                    "stringA": "prefix1/suffix-stuff-lkalalajskljlklj",
                    "stringB": "prefix2/suffix-stuff-aljksdljsd"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "sarah",
            "profession": "developer",
            "clients": [
                {
                    "name": "george",
                    "instance": "0",
                    "stringA": "prefix1/suffix-stuff-xx-klasjdlk",
                    "stringB": "prefix2/suffix-stuff-yy-lkajsldf",
                    "stringC": "prefix3/suffix-stuff-lkklkl-lkasjdl"
                },
                {
                    "name": "anna",
                    "instance": "4",
                    "stringA": "prefix1/suffix-stuff-aa-lkadslkjjj",
                    "stringB": "prefix3/suffix-stuff-bb-lkasdjfl",
                    "stringC": "prefix2/suffix-stuff-cc-lkasjdf"
                },
                {
                    "name": "michael",
                    "instance": "0",
                    "stringA": "prefix1/suffix-stuff-ttlkajlksdfsd",
                    "stringB": "prefix2/suffix-stuff-rrklajsdlf",
                    "stringC": "prefix3/suffix-stuff-lkljlkjxx"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is obviously a contrived example but it exactly matches my JSON structure.

My goal is to modify values for "stringA" and "stringB" but only for "people" with name == "bob" and only for "clients" with "instance" != "0".

I've read dozens of stackoverflow posts and other google search results, and I've tried dozens (maybe 100's) of variations of jq commands but no luck--not even close. I've tried '..' and walk, and various recursive functions that others have written (written prior to the availability of '..' and walk, I think). My difficulty seems to be related to needing the entire JSON printed out but with conditional changes based on .people[].name and .people[].clients[].instance.

I really have no idea how this works, I guess.

If I run the above JSON data through a command such as

`jq --arg name bob --arg prefix newprefix 'some-mysterious-jq-statements'`

I want the output to be this:

```
{
    "misc": {
        "color": "blue",
        "id": "yyyy-12345",
        "birthdate": "2020-12-25",
        "tools": [
            {
                "type": "power",
                "name": "hammer"
            },
            {
                "type": "manual",
                "name": "grinder"
            }
        ]
    },
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "bob",
            "profession": "analyst",
            "clients": [
                {
                    "name": "alice",
                    "instance": "3",
                    "stringA": "newprefix/suffix-stuff-xyz-aksdjf"
                },
                {
                    "name": "richard",
                    "instance": "2",
                    "stringA": "newprefix/suffix-stuff-lkasjdlflsd",
                    "stringB": "newprefix/suffix-stuff-lllaksjllsdkf",
                    "stringC": "prefix3/suffix-stuff-jhfhklasldj"
                },
                {
                    "name": "melanie",
                    "instance": "0",
                    "stringA": "prefix1/suffix-stuff-lkalalajskljlklj",
                    "stringB": "prefix2/suffix-stuff-aljksdljsd"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "sarah",
            "profession": "developer",
            "clients": [
                {
                    "name": "george",
                    "instance": "0",
                    "stringA": "prefix1/suffix-stuff-xx-klasjdlk",
                    "stringB": "prefix2/suffix-stuff-yy-lkajsldf",
                    "stringC": "prefix3/suffix-stuff-lkklkl-lkasjdl"
                },
                {
                    "name": "anna",
                    "instance": "4",
                    "stringA": "prefix1/suffix-stuff-aa-lkadslkjjj",
                    "stringB": "prefix3/suffix-stuff-bb-lkasdjfl",
                    "stringC": "prefix2/suffix-stuff-cc-lkasjdf"
                },
                {
                    "name": "michael",
                    "instance": "0",
                    "stringA": "prefix1/suffix-stuff-ttlkajlksdfsd",
                    "stringB": "prefix2/suffix-stuff-rrklajsdlf",
                    "stringC": "prefix3/suffix-stuff-lkljlkjxx"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice that the person "bob" has had modifications to the values for stringA and stringB for two of his clients, "alice" and "richard".  Nothing else has changed.

Thank you for your time and assistance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Traverse to the desired locations using `select` to filter (I added `// empty` to ignore fields producing `null`), then update `|=` to your desired value using `sub` for a regex substitution.

```bash
jq --arg name bob --arg prefix newprefix '
  (.people[] | select(.name == $name).clients[]
  | select(.instance != "0") | (.stringA, .stringB) // empty)
  |= sub("^.*/"; $prefix + "/")
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/M8CzBLqp34S)

Comment: all I can do is smfh and say, "wow, that was fast!" thank you! :)

Comment: @user1523677 You're welcome. Note that in your desired output, `.people[0].clients[1].stringC` also gets the "newprefix" while the question only asks for changing `.stringA` and `.stringB`. Please adapt if `.stringC` should be included.

Comment: ah, good eye. Actually, the change to stringC in my example output was a typo on my part. Thank you again! :)  I still have soooo much to learn about jq, but I love the tool!

Answer (score 0):

The following has the advantage of being portable, e.g. it works with jaq as well as jq:

```
.people |= map(
   if .name == $name
   then .clients |= map(
      if .instance != "0"
      then if .stringA then .stringA |= sub("prefix[^/]*"; $prefix) else . end
      | if .stringB then .stringB |= sub("prefix[^/]*"; $prefix) else . end
      else . end)
   else . end)
```

Comment: that's very nice, as well. I'm learning from both approaches. thank you!